# How to display the code of an image after tf.decode_image

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to see how the tf decode images so I try

```
import tensorflow as tf
image1 = tf.image.decode_png('/usr/src/pycharm-2017.1/bin/pycharm.png')
print(image1.shape)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    img = sess.run(image1)
    print(img.shape, img)
```

but it raise the error

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Invalid PNG header, data size 39
 [[Node: DecodePng = DecodePng[channels=0, dtype=DT_UINT8, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](DecodePng/contents)]]
```

Also I've tried  tf.image.decode_image, but it didn't work either.
What's wrong ? How can I fix it?
Thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.image.decode_png` accepts a Tensor of type string, so you need to read the png with Tensorflow before passing it to the function:

```
import tensorflow as tf
image1 = tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file('/usr/src/pycharm-2017.1/bin/pycharm.png'))
print(image1.shape)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    img = sess.run(image1)
    print(img.shape, img)
```